# disable prev button on current month bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

I've built a calendar using ux solutions bootstrap datepicker. 
I'm trying to disable the previous button when on current month.

I've tried using beforeShowDay but with no joy.

If someone can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated

Pen of what i have: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wobrjg

JS:

```
var active_dates = ["11/11/2016", "12/11/2016", "13/11/2016", "14/11/2016", "15/11/2016", "16/11/2016", "24/11/2016", "25/11/2016", "26/11/2016", "27/11/2016", "28/11/2016", "29/11/2016", "30/11/2016", "1/12/2016", "11/12/2016", "12/12/2016", "13/12/2016", "14/12/2016", "15/12/2016", "16/12/2016"];

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
     format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
     autoclose: true,
     todayHighlight: true,
     maxViewMode: 0,
     daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
     beforeShowDay: function(date){
         var d = date;
         var curr_date = d.getDate();
         var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
         var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
         var formattedDate = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year

           if ($.inArray(formattedDate, active_dates) != -1){
               return {
                  classes: 'booked'
               };
           }
          return;
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `startDate` option of datepicker.

```
/* getting first date of current month */
var date = new Date();
var first_date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);

/* using this first_date as startDate for the plugin */
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
     format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
     startDate: first_date,
     autoclose: true,
     todayHighlight: true,
     maxViewMode: 0,
 //beforeShowMonth: 0,
     daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
     beforeShowDay: function(date){
         var d = date;
         var curr_date = d.getDate();
         var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
         var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
         var formattedDate = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year

           if ($.inArray(formattedDate, active_dates) != -1){
               return {
                  classes: 'booked'
               };
           }
          return;
      }
  });
```